# Is it possible to detect radio photons?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

What is the largest wavelength of electromagnetic radiation that can produce quantum effects that we can detect?
Radio, microwave?

What are the constraints to measure photons of larger wavelengths?

Edit: I'm not looking for radiation you can measure with an antenna. But measured with an system that may measure a single photon at a time.

Comment: it is possible to detect radio photons? yes, you need an antenna. If you tune correctly you can even enjoy it.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by a "quantum effect." For instance, there's a spectral line of atomic hydrogen at a wavelength of 21cm, in the microwave band; this is actually how we locate cool hydrogen clouds in the Milky Way.

Comment: Does tuning an oscillator to produce quantum absorption behavior (in say, cesium or rubidium) count? That gets you to ~3 cm.

Comment: magnetic resonance imaging uses 64MHz when the field is around 1.5T

Comment: In Pieter's answer to the question he points out, the longest wavelength measured that way is 90$\mu$m. Radio is from kHz to low GHz, so kilometers to centimeters, so still quite far off from single photon detection.